# How to check if a column has hideable option or not?

Tags: extjs

How do we check if a column has hideable option or not in column menu header in grid panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is built from the column config, thus:

```
var col_model = grid.getColumnModel();

for (var i = 0, len = col_model.config.length; i < len; i++) {
  var column = col_model.config[i];

  // Access column properties here, such as hidden
}
```

Comment: how can we know if a checknox for a column is checked or unchekd in column header menu becuase column.hideable is always true if it is made visible in the grid or not.

Comment: hideable says if you can hide it, hidden says if it's hidden or not which directly relates to what you want.

Comment: i had problems in retaining the grid settings when page is refreshed. I had to change the settings apply state and worked fine.

Thanks a lot.